# How do i generate a 4 x 5 matrix full of random numbers with ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby, matrix

I have been trying to generate a matrix that is size 4x5 and full of random numbers by doing the following (in ruby 1.8.7):

```
m_rand = Matrix #create an empty matrix

n = 0
for n in 0...5        
    m=0
    for m in 0...4
        m_rand[n,m] = rand()
    end 
end
```

But the above does not appear to work, in particular I am not sure how to create an empty matrix of arbitrary size and then populate afterwards in ruby 1.8.7

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
m_rand = Array.new(4){Array.new(5){rand} }
```

Comment: if m_rand is defined as above, will matrix operations work on it? I had assumed m_rand explicitly need to be defined as a Matrix object

Comment: +1, this is more or less what the `build` ruby 1.9 method does.

Answer (score 4):

This allows you to create a matrix of arbitrary size with random numbers:

```
Matrix.build(rows, cols) { |row, col| rand }
```

Comment: I believe the build function was only introduced from ruby version 1.9.2/1.9.3 onwards

Comment: Good to know. I'll still leave it here, since it does pretty much exactly what the answerer wants and is more abstract than the other solutions.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
require 'matrix'

rows = (0...5).map do
  (0...4).map do
    rand()
  end 
end

m_rand = Matrix[rows]
```

Comment: The above doesn't appear to initialise a matrix object from what I can see? How would I call an individual matrix element after the above code?

Comment: Actually I just realised this creates an array as opposed to a Matrix object. The advantage of using the existing Matrix class is the pre-built matrix operations. For example if m_rand was a Matrix I could do m_rand*m_rand

Comment: @Zakoff - Sorry about that. I thought you were talking about a 2d array. See edited answer for doing this with the Matrix class.